# How to prevent Wi-Fi from turning on by itself

Tags: wi-fi

How can I prevent/stop Wi-Fi from turning on automatically? I do not want to have the Wi-Fi on when I am just using my Android device as a phone.

Comment: It normally does not switch to on automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by turning on? You turn it off but it doesn't stay that way? That sounds wrong.

Comment: It would help to know your phone model, Android version, and service provider.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your will to help. I have a Huawei MT7-LO9 with Emui 4.0. I have tried to put all wifi options off, but still the wifi goes on all the time (looking for possivle wifi connection).